# Removing last empty row of dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have some empty datagridview which uses data source is List through BindingSource. Because AllowUserToAddRows = true, initially the datagridview has one empty row. When I just select this row and close the form then datagridview creates new empty object. Why it does it? How to prevent this?
Thanks.

Selecting of empty row:
[image]
And I get this:
[image]

**Conclusion:** After many attempts to find a solution I decided to create UI control with datagridview and two buttons (add row and delete row). At this point I stopped trying to do as planned, but I'd still be pleased to know solutions.

Comment: >>> uses data source is List through BindingSource. Can you post how this is done ?

Comment: >>> When I just select this row and close the form then datagridview creates new empty object. Every re-open creates a new row ? say 1st open shows 2 rows then second time shows three rows etc..?

Comment: Every reopen creates a new row if I've selected the "newRow" at closing form. I.e., the row with asterisk.

Answer (score 8):

You can handle `RowValidating` event to verify if row is empty. If so, then cancel event and row will not be added.

```
if (gridView[0, e.RowIndex].Value == null)
    e.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: I'm trying to handle this event, but it suspends form and does not allow anything, except closing form.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there will always be an empty row at the bottom of a DataGridView. It allows the user to add new data at run-time; all they have to do is start typing in the new row.

To disable it, you will also need to prevent the user from adding new rows. Do this by setting the AllowUserToAddRows property of your DataGridView control to False:

**myDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;**

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to make sure that you are not incrementing the value of `RowCount` property in the event handlers like `RowLeave`, `CellLeave` etc.

For example:

```
DataGridView1.RowCount += 1;
```

Comment: No, I do not increase the rowCount programmatically.

Comment: What is mapped with `EditMode' property ? Can you please discuss any event you handled for datagridview ?

Comment: Do you update your binding source ? If yes, then where ? Make sure not Binding source do not get update with the new row. before update set `AllowUserToAddRows=false`

Answer (score 1):

[image]
You can disable "Enabled Adding" in here

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
gridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
```

Just disable the Adding & Deleting option for the user