# Prevent DataGridView from adding empty row to BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` (`AllowUserToAddRows = true, EditMode = EditOnKeystrokeOrF2`) bound to a `BindingSource` (bound to a `DataTable`).
My `DataGridView` has a `ComboBoxColumn` where I can select countries.

The `DataGridView` has `AllowUserToAddRows` on `true` because the user should be able to add rows by selecting a country from the blank "new row" that every `DataGridView` has.

The problem is that whenever I click on the empty row with my mouse it adds the new row to my `BindingSource`. However, the new "blank" row for the `DataGridView` doesn't appear until you actually select a country from the former (clicked) new row.

Therefore, the user doesn't know he added a new row. And the row has `DBNull.Value` as `Country` because nothing was selected. When trying to save, it throws an error because the `Country` can't be null.

So I need to prevent the new row from being added to the `BindingSource` before a value is selected from the `ComboboxColumn`.

I tried `RowValidating`-Event to cancel the edit when `Country` is `DBNull`, but it prevents me from leaving the new row. That is not what I want.

Basically, I think I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344407/removing-last-empty-row-of-datagridview) problem, without the "closing form" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the `DataGridView` lose focus before I called my Save method (which calls `Update` on my `DataAdapter`) made the empty row disappear from my `BindingSource`.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Blank' row that exists in the data grid view is there just for the addition of new rows, it doesn't exist in the datasource, until you actually click there.  Once you make an edit to that 'new row' area and move off the row, the datagridview will add another 'new row' area.  My suggestion would be to add some validation before save and exclude any rows failing validation.